Atlassian Confluence Error Through Nginx/CloudFront Reverse Proxy
I'm trying to map public links path to a shorter path.
I'm using a Nginx reverse proxy.
The same happens with CloudFront.
This is the configuration:
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://my-domain.atlassian.net/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
    location /testdoc {
        proxy_pass https://my-domain.atlassian.net/wiki/external/SOME_PUBLIC_LINK_ID;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}

When I go to localhost:80/wiki/external/SOME_PUBLIC_LINK_ID everything works but when I go to localhost:80/testdoc I get the error "We couldn't find what you're looking for". I can see that one of the requests to /cgraphql "internalFrontendResource" get 403.
